# Award a bounty less than 48 hours after posting

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I just read one of the [best answers I've ever seen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245574/3169) on stackexchange.  Accurate, detailed, clear, and not too verbose.

The only way I know to pay tribute is to offer a bounty, but [help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) says I can't offer a bounty until the question is two days old.

Is there any other option?  Can that restriction be lifted?

Comment: Not only does the question have to be two days old, but the system also makes you wait a day after starting the bounty before you can award it, so you'd still have to wait. I'm [attempting to get that oddness changed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268362/145982), but haven't heard anything

Comment: @Michael Mrozek Thanks, keep fighting the good fight. :)